# How Can I Control Emission Strength from a Light's Power Using a Driver

Tags: lighting, drivers, emission

I'm trying to set up a material's "Emission Strength" so that it is controlled by an area light's "Power" value (for example, adjust the light's power, and the emission strength adjusts likewise) I'm experimenting with a "Single Property" driver type.

Does anyone know if this can be done with drivers? If so, what should the set-up look like?

Thank you.

[image: Light Settings]

[image: Driver set-up attempt...]

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on source, "Copy as New Driver", then Right-click on target, "Paste Driver".

You can additionally edit the driver to switch to a scripted expression if you want to adjust the ratio or use a more advanced formula.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Change Prop ID: to "Light", choose the controller light, then copy the data path of the light's "Power" to the driver's "Path:"

[image]

[image]